# How to Create JPanels in a Loop and insert them in JPanel Array [] []

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jframe, jpanel

Hi guys I'm using Eclipse and I'm trying to create a Connect4 Game Grid , which is an JPanel gridArray [6] [7]. I later add the different Panels for buttons and the grid into a main panel and add it into my frame.

My Problem:
I want to fill the gridArray JPanel with Pictures of an empty field(white color) but first of all i want to create a new Panel and insert it into my gridArray through a loop until gridArray has all 42 Panels inside it and is fully filled. I have my Code below but somehow it doesnt work, although my logic should be fine.

I tried it with using a helper Function to create a new JPanel and call the function for each loop in fillGrid();, basically calling it 42 times but it still wont work...

I will gladly appreciate some help!

```java
package connect4;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridTest extends JFrame {

    JFrame mainWindow;
    JPanel buttonPanel, mainPanel;
    JPanel gridPanel;
    JPanel emptyPanel;
    JPanel panel1;
    ImageIcon emptyBox;
    JPanel[][] gridArray;

    JLabel emptyLabel;

    JButton arrow1,arrow2,arrow3,arrow4,arrow5,arrow6,arrow7;

    public GridTest() {
        createGameGrid();
        fillGrid();
    }

    public void createGameGrid() {

        //creating window and mainpanel
        mainWindow = new JFrame("Connect 4");
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //defining top panel with 7 buttons;
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 7));

        arrow1 = new JButton("V");
        arrow2 = new JButton("V");
        arrow3 = new JButton("V");
        arrow4 = new JButton("V");
        arrow5 = new JButton("V");
        arrow6 = new JButton("V");
        arrow7 = new JButton("V");

        buttonPanel.add(arrow1);
        buttonPanel.add(arrow2);
        buttonPanel.add(arrow3);
        buttonPanel.add(arrow4);
        buttonPanel.add(arrow5);
        buttonPanel.add(arrow6);
        buttonPanel.add(arrow7);

        //create Grind Panel
        gridPanel = new JPanel();
        gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,7));

        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        mainWindow.add(mainPanel);
        mainWindow.pack();
        mainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel greateOnePanel(){
      //here we need to insert the icon which is in empty box into a newly created panel   
      //ifirst wanted to insert black panels do ensure it works as intended but it doesnt
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.setSize(50,50);

        return panel;
    }

    //here we need to fill the grid with the panels created above from left to right...
    public void fillGrid() {
       for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
          for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
            gridPanel.add(greateOnePanel());

          }
       }
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     new GridTest();
   }
}
```

i tried it with this method using gridArray, but it throws NullPointer Exeptions and wont fill the grid with simple textlabels "Hallo" (just for testing purposes)

```
public void fillGrid() {
        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
          for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {

             JLabel label = new JLabel("Hallo"); 

            gridArray[j][k] = new JPanel();
            gridArray[j][k].setSize(50, 50);
            gridArray[j][k].setBackground(Color.RED);
            gridArray[j][k].add(label);
            gridPanel.add(gridArray[j][k]);


          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am no expert, but 42 panels.. Are you sure that's the best solution? Afaik you should need no more than one single JPanel.

Comment: i want to use an ImageIcon, insert it into a Panel, and insert the Panel into my gridArray Panel.

Comment: You are almost there, use a LayoutManager, like BorderLayout. (j, k) as parameters to determine the image.

Comment: @JoopEggen, i get your idea, but first i want to fill it with empty black panels. any Idea  why it wont work?

Comment: Try `setPreferredSize(50, 50)` and better `mainPanel.add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);`

Comment: still doesnt work. i dont know whats wrong. im stuck.  i tried with : ```public void fillGrid() {
     for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
       for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
         
       JLabel label = new JLabel("Hallo"); 
        
      gridArray[j][k] = new JPanel();
         gridArray[j][k].setSize(50, 50);
         gridArray[j][k].setBackground(Color.RED);
         gridArray[j][k].add(label);
         gridPanel.add(gridArray[j][k]);
         

       }
     }
 }```  somehow it wont even fill the grid with "hallo" labels...

Comment: Don't put code here. Edit the post and put it below instead :)

Comment: i did update, you can now look ^^. i tried basically everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short, self contained, code that should help with various aspects of the task.

There is no need for a panel in each cell. The only thing it helped with was setting a BG color. That can be done in a label as long as the background is set to opaque.

This code defines a `SquareLabel` which overrides `getPreferredSize()` to return the maximum of preferred width and height as the value of both (usually it is the width).

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class SquareLabelGrid {

    int rows = 6;
    int cols = 7;
    JLabel[][] labelArray = new JLabel[cols][rows];
    Font bigFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 30);
    Insets labelInsets;

    SquareLabelGrid() {
        JPanel gameBoard = new JPanel(new GridLayout(rows, cols));
        // a border to make the cell boundaries more clear and add 
        // some space around the text
        Border border = new CompoundBorder(
                new LineBorder(Color.BLACK),new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));
        for (int yy = 0; yy < rows; yy++) {
            for (int xx = 0; xx < cols; xx++) {
                JLabel l = getColoredSquareLabel(xx, yy);
                labelArray[xx][yy] = l;
                gameBoard.add(l);
                l.setBorder(border);
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gameBoard);
    }

    private JLabel getColoredSquareLabel(int x, int y) {
        SquareLabel label = new SquareLabel(
                String.format("%1s,%1s", (x+1), (y+1)));
        label.setFont(bigFont);
        label.setOpaque(true); // so we can see the BG color
        label.setBackground(Color.ORANGE); // I prefer orange!
        // make the GUI less 'crowded'
        label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4)); 

        return label;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            new SquareLabelGrid();
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class SquareLabel extends JLabel {

    SquareLabel(String label) {
        super(label);
    }

    /* This will create a square component that accounts for the 
     size of the String / Icon it contains. No guesswork! */
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();
        int w = d.width;
        int h = d.height;
        int sz = w > h ? w : h;

        return new Dimension(sz, sz);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have not initialized the grid array .
Otherwise it will throw Null pointer exception.

```
JPanel[][] gridArray = new JPanel[6][8];
```

Also set the preferred size of main panel to make the grids visible .

```
mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
```

Here is what i can see when I run your code with the modifications mentioned here .
[image]

Also please execute it from main with following code .

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GridTest();
            }
        });    

   }
```

Comment: *"Also set the preferred size of main panel to make the grids visible"* Messing with the preferred size is best avoided. If it turns out to be necessary (like with a custom painted panel), better to override the `getPreferredSize()` and (possibly) take into account the preferred size returned by the parent.